# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{\sqrt n}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is this series convergent?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{\sqrt n}}$$

Edit: I'm sorry I wrote a double negative. This is the series.
(thanks Brian M. Scott for editing)

Comment: Go to the FAQ section adn read the directions there to use LaTeX in this site.

Comment: Probably you do not mean a negative exponent at the bottom.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is one place to start learning how to write mathematics here.

Comment: If the exponent downstairs is negative, the terms grow without bound. So no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $2^{\sqrt{n}}=e^{(\log 2)\sqrt{n}}$.

By looking at the power series expansion of $e^x$, we can see that for positive $x$, we have $e^x\gt \frac{x^8}{8!}$. Thus 
$$e^{\log 2\sqrt{n}}\gt \frac{(\log 2)^8}{8!}n^4.$$

So the $n$-th term of our sequence is $\lt \frac{8!}{(\log 2)^8}\frac{1}{n^2}$.
Comparison with the convergent series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ shows that our series converges.

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: Wow thank you great answer! It actually helped me with some other series I had problems with!

Comment: You are welcome. There are easier ways, since there is lots of slack, the terms go down really fast. But I have a fondness for explicit (even if weak) bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^{-\sqrt n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{\sqrt n}n^2$$

But this series clearly diverges since $\,2^{\sqrt n}n^2\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0\,$

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not convergent, since the $n^2/2^{-\sqrt n}\to\infty$ for $n\to\infty$. But 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{2^{\sqrt n}} $$
converges, because the summands go to zero faster than $1/n^2$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^2}{2^{-\sqrt{n}}}={n^2}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$$which does not converge to $0$. Therefore, the series cannot converge.